# Xpages web analytics that is not Google Analytics. Can it be installed locally on the server?

Tags: analytics

I have an Xpages website that  is very secure and has a requirement to have comprehensive user tracking.  Therefore the use of things like Google analytics is not viable as it sends user data out from the server (customer requirement that web tracking be loaded on server).

What web analytics software can I install on the server, that will give me feature rich tracking for (SSL delivered pages )so that I can see what each user is doing and perhaps where they are struggling or loosing interest etc.

In other words, everything google anaytics gives me, but one installed on the server.

Thanks 
Damien

Answer (score 1):

you might want to ask that question on serverfault or webmasters since it isn't actually a programming question

Answer (score 1):

You could use: [AWstats from SourceForge](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) - and Chuck Connell has some other suggestions in a [SearchDomino article](http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Domino-Web-traffic-analyzers).

/John

Answer (score 0):

As Stephan said, question belongs to serverfault. Nevertheless, check out http://piwik.org/